# How to use PI in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, pi

I am trying to write a batch file so it executes a program I did with different arguments. One of those arguments is often the number PI.

How can I get the number Pi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume with "batch file" you mean a Windows batch file.

There is no pre-defined constant for PI, so you need to hardcode that into the batchfile:

```
set PI=3.14159
yourProgram.exe %PI%
```